# Selenium Webdriver c# : Getting "The path is not of a legal form." while initializing FirefoxProfile

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using below mentioned code to initialize a firefox driver with service, options and timeout.

```
var Service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(RunConfig.DriverPath);
Service.HideCommandPromptWindow = RunConfig.HideDriverCommandPromptWindow;
var Options = new FirefoxOptions();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RunConfig.PathToBrowserBinary))
       Options.BrowserExecutableLocation = RunConfig.PathToBrowserBinary;

Options.Profile = new FirefoxProfile();
Options.Profile.SetPreference(Preference.Name,PathToDownloadFolder));
Options.Profile.SetPreference(Preference.Name, Preference.Value);
return new FirefoxDriver(Service, Options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
```

But it gives me an error that The path is not of legal for while initializing firefox profile

Comment: Could you post the paths you have defined?

Comment: PathToBrowserBinary = "" and PathToDownloadFolder = "./"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was the seleniumwebdriver dll I was using is present in some other project. Adding the selenium webdriver and support dll to the current project worked.